# Arduino building a pulse proportional thermostat

Tags: arduino, temperature, heat, power-electronics

I'm not much of an engineer, but I have worked with arduino.  I'm looking to see if it's possible to build a pulse proportional thermostat with a probe and an arduino.  Any recommendations on where to begin would be appreciated.  Note: I couldn't find an arduino shield for something like this, so I thought asking here would be a good start.

Comment: Would that be an analog to [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) converter? Use [analogWrite();](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite) to one of the PWM pins on Arduino.

Comment: Could you describe what you expect the pulse to look like? Does it get wider with temperature? How often is the pulse expected to be produced? Once per second? Hundreds of times per second or more? What voltage level does the pulse need to be? Does it need to be voltage or should it be current?

Comment: Sounds like a PID with a PWM output where the PWM window is a couple of minutes? But I am only guessing, since there is not much info here...